# Save mp3 file to ios phone programmatically

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

In my application, I show list of `mp3` file from `Ressource`, and I want give user possibility to `download` this files, for that I use a `Function/Method` like that

```
func downloadClicked(sender: UIButton){


       UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum(NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("level-complete", ofType:"mp3")!, nil, nil, nil);

}
```

I have no exception, but I can't find this `**mp3**` in my local library (i use application vlc to check that and itunes)

how can I achieve that please ?

Comment: I think you can't save audio to photo album.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps:

### Reference:

http://www.raywenderlich.com/1914/nscoding-tutorial-for-ios-how-to-save-your-app-data

```
NSData *dataMp3 = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL: localMp3File.url];

//Get path directory
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

//Create Download directory
documentsDirectory = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Mp3"];
[[NSFileManager defaultManager] documentsDirectory withIntermediateDirectories:YES attributes:nil error:nil];

NSString *filePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", documentsDirectory, @"your-file-name"];

[dataMp3 writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
```